# Filtering notifications

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications

Is it possible to filter the notification that my Android device shows to me? For example I'd like to filter out the notifications about apps getting updated.

(I use CyanogenMod 9 if that matters.)

Comment: When you say "filter the notification", do you mean "filter out" (as in do not show them) or "filter for" (as in explicitly display them)?

Comment: Also, app shopping is off-topic on the site, so you may wish to edit your question in the form of "How do I..." as opposed to "find me an app that does ..."

Comment: I meant filter out.

Answer (score 1):

Most apps should give you control of their own notifications via their internal settings.  For your specific example, app update notifications are coming from the Play Store app, and can be toggled on or off from within the app itself via `menu -> Settings -> Notifications.`  Other built-in apps like Gmail or Talk, or 3rd-party apps like Yahoo! Mail or Facebook for example, have similar controls that allow you to adjust notifications with varying degree of control (e.g. frequency, etc.)

In Android 4.1 and above, Google introduced a way to completely disable notifications for certain apps that either don't have such settings at all, or don't offer enough control for your liking (or include aggressive advertisements via push-notifications like AirPush).  Long-pressing a notification and tapping the new `App Info` option will bring up properties of the app that spawned it, and from there you can completely turn them off.  This feature appears in most custom ROMs as well that are based on the Jelly Bean (Android OS version 4.1.x/4.2.x) code base (CyanogenMod 10 in your case.)

Comment: Regarding the Play Store app, I have "Notifications" disabled but I still get notifications. The sad truth is that even the apps that do let you control their notifications, don't have controls that are fine-grained enough. It's not that I don't want to receive all notifications from the app, it's only some of them. If I cancel all the notifications from a certain app, I might be missing some important notifications. So really I don't see how what you're proposing is helping me.